# The correct json format for this?

Tags: php, javascript, json

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "necklaces": [
                { title: "Outlet", url: "W_Outlet" },
                { title: "Baby-G", url: "W_BabyG" },
                { title: "Bulova", url: "W_Bulova" },
                { title: "Children_s", url: "W_Childrens" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use `json_decode` in PHP I get an empty result, which leads me to believe that the JSON isn't formatted correctly.

What I need is: An object named 'categories', and inside that object there will be an array of objects which have an array of objects inside them.

i.e. Category -> [ Necklaces -> { title: 'Gold', url: 'Gold' } ]

and so on, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Try http://jsonlint.org/. All keys must be strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "necklaces": [
                {
                    "title": "Outlet",
                    "url": "W_Outlet"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Baby-G",
                    "url": "W_BabyG"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Bulova",
                    "url": "W_Bulova"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Children_s",
                    "url": "W_Childrens"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around your field names.

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "necklaces": [
                { "title": "Outlet", "url": "W_Outlet" },
                { "title": "Baby-G", "url": "W_BabyG" },
                { "title": "Bulova", "url": "W_Bulova" },
                { "title": "Children_s", "url": "W_Childrens" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `title` and `url` must be quoted:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "categories": [
        {
            "necklaces": [
                { "title": "Outlet", "url": "W_Outlet" },
                { "title": "Baby-G", "url": "W_BabyG" },
                { "title": "Bulova", "url": "W_Bulova" },
                { "title": "Children_s", "url": "W_Childrens" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

$b = json_decode($json);
print_r($b);

?>
```

And the result will be:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [necklaces] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [title] => Outlet
                                    [url] => W_Outlet
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [title] => Baby-G
                                    [url] => W_BabyG
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [title] => Bulova
                                    [url] => W_Bulova
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [title] => Children_s
                                    [url] => W_Childrens
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: i'd further generalize it by saying that all keys and values must be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

All keys and values must be String in JSON , You were missing quotes .

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "necklaces": [
                {
                    "title": "Outlet",
                    "url": "W_Outlet"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Baby-G",
                    "url": "W_BabyG"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Bulova",
                    "url": "W_Bulova"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Children_s",
                    "url": "W_Childrens"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to test JSON.